# ASP.Net Membership Only allow people to access actions when logged in

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership

I'm learning about ASP.Net membership and I want to be able to only allow people to use certain actions if they are logged in.  I am currently using the default template for ASP.Net membership provided by Microsoft when you create a new internet application project using MVC 4.  I have tried marking actions with the [Authorize] attribute but that doesn't seem to block users who aren't logged in from viewing a page.  Is there an easy way of implementing this or another attribute I should be looking at?  I am also looking for a way to redirect people if they're not logged in to the login page?

Example Code:

```
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Register

    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
```

Comment: if you're using the [Authorize] attribute correctly that page should only be accessible by logged on users. can we see code?

Comment: I have put the code in the original comment, the register page should only be accessible to users that are logged in. (Don't ask why!)

Comment: The above should work. Try clearing your cookies, and try again.

Comment: Are you sure the users aren't already logged in and don't have a valid cookie?

Answer (score 0):

One thing I can think of is you might have Windows authentication mode.

Please make sure you are using [Forms Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa291347(v=vs.71).aspx).

For example,

```
<system.web>
   ...
   <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880"/>
   </authentication>
   ...
</system.web>
```